# Creating Custom UIActionSheet/UIView with UILabels and UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiactionsheet

As the title says, I want to create a custom UIActionSheet/UIView that has some objects inside of it like labels, buttons, table view cell, etc. I want to replicate this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nasGv.png

I am guessing that is a customized UIActionSheet that they added Labels and Images inside the buttonAtIndex or that they went ahead and did a Custom UIView and animated coming from the bottom to the top of the page. Either way, can any guide me through something like this? Any suggestions, code, links to sites, or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: That might be a child viewController.

Comment: @Jonathan That's what I was thinking but wasn't too sure.

Answer (score 3):

On iOS7, you can achieve this very easily using the new custom modal transition support in UIKit using UIModalPresentationCustom and transitioningDelegate.

Using these, you can create a view controller with a view set up to present what you need, and then present it with an animation of your choosing in the transition delegate object.

More information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

You can find great examples here how to work with the transitioning delegate here:
https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know this was possible. I will definitely look into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a custom UIView to me.  You can make your view in IB or programatically.  As far as replicating the animation, this might be helpful to you:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html

This tutorial shows from top to bottom, but you should be able to switch around the values.  Will be good to learn UIView animations using blocks which can be learned here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation

Comment: THANK YOU! This is great, amazing! If I could up vote your answer I would (only have 14 rep points). The first link is what Taylor was talking about, I'm assuming. Thank you, you came in clutch with these two links!

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please press the check mark next to the answer to show this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do 100% is calling for a custom UIView.

You have 2 general implementation options:

1. Create another view ontop of your current view, animate it in however you would like, and have the current UIViewController act as it's controller.
2. Create a separate UIViewController to handle the interactions with that view. As Leo mentioned, there is an iOS 7 API for custom transitions for View Controllers who want to present other View Controllers. You should know that this API is a bit convoluted and can be confusing at first. But, it will probably be the best way to achieve the look you presented in the picture.

If you're OK with a full screen cover, go ahead and skip the Custom Model Transition and use the UIModalPresentationFullScreen option under the new View Controller's modalPresentationStyle property.

Comment: Added a link to a great project in GitHub that demonstrates how to use the custom transitioning delegate and how to perform these animations.

Comment: That's great - examples are worth way more than docs. Just stating that, even with examples, the iOS7 custom transition API is a bit tough. And, in my opinion, isn't very baked. One example - if you handle landscape rotation, the container view that's given to you by the transitionContext doesn't recognize the current rotation. It makes you redo all of your animations for to support it.

Comment: Agree. As a whole, iOS7 is not ready. But it is still better than nothing because to implement these in iOS6, it is really annoying and you have to do a lot of hand holding with parent/child controllers.

Comment: @TaylorHalliday: I was actually looking into and thinking of doing a modal transition/segue since I already know how to do it and wouldn't be as difficult, but I want to learn and discover other options as well. Thanks for the info, I will try to animate it and go with option 1. Will probably do option 2 on the side.